# Facebook DialogBox

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom-events

I was someone who wanted to learn PHP,
and I found a problem in my learning.
Can you help me?

I want to create a dialog box using the following script.
The calling process this page is displayed in the dialog box like this example:

http://www.berthojoris.com/form-fb/

If the profile menu is clicked it will show a pop up html page profile that I have made. I want to ask is if I want to turn the script into the login dialog box for how?
If successful, the dialogue that will inform the process works and if it fails dialog will tell you that the login process fails.
Can I be helped to be made a function based on the example I have?

My script can be downloaded at: http://www.mediafire.com/?3ti12n4jc29occl

Comment: Please post the part of the source in question.  I don't really want to unzip your file.